# Isn't clip path resizable for mozilla browser

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am using d3 to build a scatterplot chart in which i have used clip path to give the zoom functionality in my chart. But the height and width of the clip path is remainig constant only when i open the page in mozilla browser.
This is working absolutely fine with chrome browser. Even if i decrease or increase the size of clip path its taking the default width and height for mozilla browser. Also when i change the rect to circle it takes the clip path as a rect. This problem is only with the mozilla browser. My code:

```
that.svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
                .append('svg')
                .attr("width",that.w)
                .attr("height",that.height)
                .attr("id","svgcontainer")
                .attr("class","svgcontainer");

that.group = that.svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate("+(that.margin_left)+","+(that.margin_top)+")")
                .attr("id","main");
clip = that.group.append("svg:clipPath")
                        .attr("id", "clip")
                        .append("svg:rect")
                        .attr("width",(that.w-that.margin_left-that.margin_right))
                        .attr("height", that.height-that.margin_top-that.margin_bottom);

chartBody = that.group.append("g")
                        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

So please suggest me some alternative.

Comment: The issue is that the clipPath width and height is remaining constant and it is not changing on firefox. So the bubbles in the scatter plot are getting cut due to the height and width of clippath. Even if i increase the height of clipPath it still remains the same, it does not change.

Comment: I understand your concern but it wont be possible for us to publish the code to any testing server at this stage of development. But yes, if you can just tell me whether firefox actually has any such problem with clippath not getting any custom width / height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me,  it must be your code (some part you haven't shown probably) that's wrong.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120"
     viewPort="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <script>
        i = 0;
        function go() {
            var circle = document.getElementById("c");
            if (i == 0) {
              ++i;
              circle.setAttribute("r", "25");
              return;
            }
            var clip = document.getElementById("myClip");
            clip.removeChild(circle);
            var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            rect.setAttribute("x", "50");
            rect.setAttribute("y", "50");
            rect.setAttribute("width", "20");
            rect.setAttribute("height", "30");
            clip.appendChild(rect);
        }
    </script>
    
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
          clip-path="url(#myClip)" onclick="go()"/>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue was because i had multiple clipPath in the single web page with same id so in firefox it was taking the width and height of first clipPath and was applying the same attributes for rest all clipPaths.